# Where are cargo log messages stored?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, logfile

When I build a Rust project using `cargo build`, I get error messages in the terminal. Are these error messages stored in a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but if you'd like to store them, you can use `cargo build 2>./log`, which redirects all errors to be written to the file `./log`.

Comment: If the logs are meant to be machine-read, `rustc` and `cargo` have `--error-format json` and `--message-format json` respectively.